# jQuery fit in screen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there any jquery plugins which, for a given DOM element, will tell me if it fits in screen or not, and if possible, to return the overflow values (so i can adjust the `top`, `left` positions properly before displaying the popup.

I am using it like this:

```
<div class="popup-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="popup-trigger">Button</button>
    <div class="popup" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
        Popup content
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a javascript function that shows the popup:

```
$("body").on("click", ".popup-trigger", function () {
    var $button = $(this),
        $popup = $button.closest(".popup-wrapper").children(".popup");

    // TODO set popup position to fit screen
    $popup.show();
});
```

Comment: With *'oveflow values'*, you mean the difference between the widths / heights? Or something more complex, like the distance from each side of the window to each side of the DOM element?

Comment: `distance from each side of the window to each side of the DOM element`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function may suit you:

```
function getBox(element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var offset = $el.offset();
    var eWidth = $el.outerWidth();
    var eHeight = $el.outerHeight();
    return  {
         left: offset.left,
         top: offset.top,
         right: wWidth - (offset.left + eWidth),
         bottom: wHeight - (offset.top + eHeight)
    }
}
```

You pass it a DOM element, jQuery object or selector, and it'll return an object with four values:

1. `left`: distance from the left side of the element to the left side of the window. If negative, the element's border starts to the left of the window.
2. `top`: the distance from the top side of the element to th top side of the window. If negative, the element's top side is above the window top.
3. `right`: the distance from the right side of the window to the ritht side of the element. If negative, the right side of the element is to the right of the window.
4. `bottom`: the distance from the bottom side of the window to the bottom side of the element. If negative, the bottom side of the element is below the bottom side of the window.

Hope it serves you!

Comment: Thanks for answer. There is a small problem, `$el.offset()` returns `top: 0, left: 0`. I think because the element has absolute position and is inside a relative position wrapper

Comment: `offset()` should return the offset relative to the document. Can you post your markup and CSS?

Comment: `.popup-wrapper { position: relative; } .popup { position: absolute; }` I've "fixed" it by getting the offset of the `popup-wrapper` instead

Comment: One thing to watch out for is what happens when the page is scrolled.  I needed to subtract ```$(window).scrollLeft()``` and ```$(window).scrollTop()``` from ```$el.offset()``` top and left, respectively.

Comment: This is almost certainly incomplete and breaky. I don't believe a robust solution is possible in under 500 LOC. There are so many DOM and CSS factors that affect the actual meaning of `width()`, `height()`, `outerWidth()`, `outerHeight()`, and most importantly `offset()`, and I see nothing in your code that attempts to control for all those quirks.